# Oracle DataReader returns 1 row but Read method returns false

Tags: c#, oracle, datareader

I have a basic sql statement that looks up a user and returns one record but when I run a block of code that says if(myReader.Read()) it returns false. I have stepped through the code and examined the reader object and it does in fact contain one record. below is the code.

sql:
SELECT user_name, user_password, user_state
  FROM users
 WHERE users.user_id = 123

```
    System.Data.Common.DbCommand _cmd = this.GetCommand(conn, _dbf, sqlText, CommandType.Text);
     System.Data.Common.DbConnection _cn = _cmd.Connection;
     System.Data.Common.DbDataReader myReader = null;

     _cn.Open();
     using(_cn) {
        myReader = _cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (myReader.Read())  {
                <object gets built here with user data returned from sql>
          }
       }
```

Comment: Does this query return results when run from sqlplus or sql developer?

Comment: yes, ran the sql in toad and it returned results. Verified the connection string was pointing to the correct database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (myReader.HasRows)
  while (myReader.Read())
  .....
```

Comment: that is how I would have done it but it is not my codebase to change. Just researching why another developers code is not working. Probably have them change it to this.