# DBReader has rows but Read() returns false

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dbconnection

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mySchema.MyTable", conn);
    conn.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {...
```

In the debugger I can see my reader has one row - I can see the data returned - but `reader.Read` is returning `false` so my processing code is not getting called.

This seems pretty basic "read rows from a database table" stuff so what am I missing? Should I be looking at the reader's row data directly or something?

Comment: How exactly do you _see_ this row in the debugger? Which property have you been looking at? Did the debugger already call `Read()` so that when your code calls it it's `false`?

Comment: Sounds like the debugger already read all the data, and your code is then detecting that there is no more data. Does this work if you don't use the debugger?

Comment: _Seriously_, the debugger can modify the behaviour of the code in this way? As in if I expand the "Results View" on `reader` it runs a `while(reader.Read()){...}` loop?

Comment: If you see the results, how should the debugger get them if not by reading them out like that? it will not start a second query...

Comment: Well the whole point of the debugger is to be a silent observer, surely? Stepping through your program line by line, etc...

Comment: What about wrapping `reader.Read()` inside another control loop outside such as `while (reader.HasRows()){reader.Read()}` ? That way you will see what's going on. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199877/oracle-datareader-returns-1-row-but-read-method-returns-false?rq=1) dealt with it the same way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you let the debugger show you the results, it will read out the reader and enumerate the result.

See the comment in the debugger window:

> Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

So your debugger already read out all results and if you step to `reader.Read()` there are no more rows to read and `Read()` returns `false`.

---

I just reproduced it with a litte test. When my debugger reads the results, my code can't read them anymore. If I don't let the debugger show them, my code can read them. (qed)

Comment: This does seem to be the issue but it's still crazy to me the debugger breaks the behaviour of the program... I can check the results returned or I can use them but not both! Is there a non-stupid way to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Mr.Boy in this special case I don't think so. On the other hand, why would you need to. To debug you can simply set break points inside your `Read()` loop. I think you can be pretty sure that the `SqlDataReader` works correctly, so I don't see a need to view the results outside/before your own reading loop.

Comment: @RenéVogt, you saved my day :) Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the reader type var to SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); resolved the issue, even I was facing same issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Which of the existing answers did help you to find that? Note that the ordering is configurable, i.e. there is no "above".

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SELECT 1;` to test you reader.
Do you have SqlManagement Studio? To test query.

It is work.

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1", conn);
            conn.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string a = "teste";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for someone. In my case I forgot to use

```
 cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

So, reader.HasRows() or reader.Read() was returning false.

Answer (score -3):

Change the reader type `var` to `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` and try this.It will work.

I have sample code for `MYSQL`

```
using (MYSQLCON)
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (YourWriter)
            {
                String Header = null;
                String Content = null;

                for (int i = 0; i <= sdr.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    Header = Header + sdr.GetName(i).ToString() + ",";
                }
                YourWriter.WriteLine(Header);
                while (sdr.Read())

                    for (int i = 0; i <= sdr.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        Content = Content + sdr[i].ToString() + ",";
                        if (i == sdr.FieldCount - 1)
                        {
                            YourWriter.WriteLine(Content);
                            Content = null;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var` is just syntactic suger. The compiler knows that it's operating on an  `SqlDataReader`. This has nothing to do with the behaviour observed by OP.